# P-value for one-tail test on the significance of the independent variable in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, t-test

I have the estimator of the slope to be $b = 443.016$. We have 29 observations.

We test

$H_0: \beta \le 450$

$H_1: \beta > 450$,

where $\beta$ is the actual slope of the simple linear regression model.

In this case,
$T_{stat}=\frac{b - \beta}{s_b} = (443.016-450)/79.46=-0.087.$

Am I right to say that the p-value is the area to the right from $T_{stat}=-0.087$ under the distribution curve? I found the p-value to be $1-0.4656=0.5344.$

I am a bit confused if I have to treat the situation differently from the situation when $T_{stat} > 0$.

Basically, is it true for the given hypotheses that the $p-value$ is the area to the right from $T_{stat}$ no matter if $T_{stat}$ is positive or negative?

Comment: Is there a reason you have not accepted Dave's answer?

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case (and in general for a “greater than” alternative hypothesis), you find the area to the right of $T_{stat}$, not the absolute value.

Consider what it would mean to get $\hat{\beta}=-9999$. You would have a very negative $T_{stat}$. That would be weak evidence against the null hypothesis, and you would expect a large p-value close to 1.

The correct p-value for you is 0.5344.